# Optional parameters in TypeScript function lead to overly vague type results

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```
const runIfTrue = <S extends boolean, T, U>(condition: S, fn: () => T, otherValue: U) => {
  return (condition === true ? fn() : otherValue) as S extends true ? T : U;
}

const foo = <P extends boolean>({ param }: { param: P }) => {
  return runIfTrue(param, () => "string", null);
}

const value1 = foo({ param: true });  // type string
const value2 = foo({ param: false }); // type null
```

This is all working fine; however, if I make `param` optional and use a double-negative operator, then it no longer gives me clarity on the type:

```
const foo = <P extends boolean>({ param }: { param?: P }) => {
  return runIfTrue(!!param, () => "string", null);
}

const value1 = foo({ param: true });  // string | null
const value2 = foo({ param: false }); // string | null
```

What is the reason for this? I'm struggling to understand how it wouldn't be able to pick up on `true` when `param` is now optional.

In my mind there are three possible scenarios:

1. `param` is provided as `true`, in which case `!!param` will still be `true` and still inferrable;
2. `param` is provided as `false`, in which case `!!param` will still be `false` and still inferrable;
3. `param` is not provided (i.e. `undefined`), in which case `!!param` will be `false`. I have considered the possibility of `param` coming from the prototype of the object; trying the same thing with `foo(Object.create(null))` didn't change this, however.

Comment: Probably TS is not able to infer the result type of `!!param` as anything more specific than `boolean`. Instead, try`({ param = false }: { param?: P }) => runIfTrue(param, () => "string", null)`